# Move face along normal while creating new vertices / faces

Tags: modeling

is there any way to move the face inward along normal without affecting other geometry so that it creates one new face between it's end location and the initial lower edge?
[image]

Comment: Alt E >Extrude Manifold?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you probably want is <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Extrude Manifold*:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much :)